# Find overlapping date ranges from two tables?

Tags: postgresql

I want to filter out the IDs of Table 1 which is not in between the date range of Table 2.

Table 1:

```
    Booking_ID | starts | ends
```

Table 2:

```
    ID | starts | ends
```

Tried to do something like this but it does not fetch the correct results. Seems like something is wrong here.

````
select t1.id, date(t1.starts), date(t1.ends) from t1
where exists (select *
              from t2
              where (date(t2.starts) not between date(t1.starts) and date(t1.ends)) or 
                    (date(t2.ends) not between date(t1.starts) and date(t1.ends)) or
                    (date(t1.starts) not between date(t2.starts) and date(t2.ends))) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `overlaps` for that:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select *
              from t2
              where (t1.starts, t1.ends) overlaps (t2.starts, t2.ends));
```

If those are `timestamp` columns and you only want to consider the `date` values, then cast the values to dates:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select *
              from t2
              where (t1.starts::date, t1.ends::date) overlaps (t2.starts::date, t2.ends::date));
```

Alternatively you can use a `daterange()`  where it's easier to control if the right hand edge should be included:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select *
              from t2
              where daterange(t1.starts::date, t1.ends::date, '[]') && daterange(t2.starts::date, t2.ends, '[]'))
```

If you want to exclude e.g. the right edge from the range, use `'[)'` instead of `'[]'`